# Pycharm python doesn't visualize decision tree

Tags: python, pycharm, visualization, graphviz, decision-tree

I've been trying to build my very first decision tree visualazation. I've been able to create the algorithm and even calculate it's accuracy, but I've never managed to produce a nice visualization of nodes splitting. I've found this piece of code on the internet:

```html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_clean.csv')
print(df.columns)
y = df['OR']
x = df.drop(['OR', 'Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)

print(y.head())
print(x.head())

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(x, y)

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image, display
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=dot_data,
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True)
G = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
plt = Image(G.create_png())
display(plt)
```

It doesn't give any valuable output (especially errors) except this in the console:

```html
/Users/arturdzieciol/anaconda3/envs/uniqa_scenarios/bin/python /Users/arturdzieciol/PycharmProjects/drzewo_decyzyjne/titanic_kaggle.py
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'OR', 'production_year', 'mileage', 'car_worth',
       'main_driver_age'],
      dtype='object')
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: OR, dtype: int64
   production_year   mileage  car_worth  main_driver_age
0           2000.0  198500.0     4770.0             59.0
1           2003.0  156000.0     7380.0             44.0
2           2014.0   30530.0    43080.0             46.0
3           2007.0  223000.0    16040.0             31.0
4           2003.0  380000.0     6930.0             42.0
<IPython.core.display.Image object>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in a notebook environment, you need to explicitly call `show()` on the implicit `plt` object:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
...
my_tree.fit(features, labels)
tree.plot_tree(my_tree)
plt.show()
```

This will cause pycharm to display a graphical rendering of your tree

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today and I am unable to find its correct solution. But I have tried one thing it worked fine for me and it created a separate a png image of decision tree

```
G.write_png("iris.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `matplotlib` to generate the decision tree as an image.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 20))
_ = plot_tree(dtree,
              filled=True,
              rounded=True,
              class_names=["alpha", "beta"]
              )

fig.savefig("tree.png")
```